# Sublime text 2: certain files should open in a different panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 for Rails development. I love the editor so far, especially its customizability. Currently I'm getting used to a 2-panel workflow where I have various Rspec files open in the right panel, and the corresponding views, controllers etc. open in the left panel. But when I open new files, they frequently open in the wrong panel (the one I'm currently working in), and I have to drag them over to the left or right manually.

Here's my question: when I open a file, is it possible to make the file open in the right panel if the file name has "_spec" in it, and in the left panel otherwise?

I know that's a pretty specific adjustment. I'd appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible via a plugin. If you have some time, I'd spend a little bit of it investigating the sublime text api. I've thrown something together that should work. It's only minimally tested, and not very robust. Though I think it should work for your use case. If it doesn't you can use making it just right part of exploring the ST api.

```
import sublime_plugin
import os


class OpenLocationListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        file_name = view.file_name()
        window = view.window()
        num_groups = window.num_groups()
        if file_name is not None and num_groups >=2:
            if "_spec" in os.path.basename(view.file_name()):
                if window.active_group() == 0:
                    window.set_view_index(view, 1, 0)
                    window.focus_view(view)
            else:
                if window.active_group() == 1:
                    window.set_view_index(view, 0, 0)
                    window.focus_view(view)
```

Save the above in your Packages/User folder as `<some name>.py` The name doesn't matter, as long as you save it as a python file.

As a side not, unless you are using an ST2 only plugin, consider upgrading to ST3. Many plugins that are under active development may only be ST3 compatible. I wrote the above in ST3, so that's where I tested, though I don't believe there is anything ST3 specific about it.

Comment: Skuroda, this plugin gives me errors in ST2 so I'll have to find time to tinker with it, or upgrade to ST3. Thanks!

Comment: Took a quick look, were you getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'num_groups'` If so, it might be a bug in the API. I'm not sure how you can have a loaded view without a window.